# jQuery/Javascript index into collection/map by object property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dictionary

I have the following Javascript defining an array of countries and their states...

```
var countryStateMap = [{"CountryCode":"CA","Name":"Canada","States":[{"StateCode":"S!","CountryCode":"CA","Name":"State 1"},{"StateCode":"S2","CountryCode":"CA","Name":"State 2"}]},"CountryCode":"US","Name":"United States","States":[{"StateCode":"S1","CountryCode":"US","Name":"State 1"}]}];
```

Based on what country the user selects, I need to refresh a select box's options for states from the selected Country object. I know I can index into the country collection with an int index like so...

```
countryStateMap[0].States
```

I need a way to get the Country by CountryCode property though. I know the following doesn't work but what I would like to do is something like this...

```
countryStateMap[CountryCode='CA'].States
```

Can this be achieved without completely rebuilding my collection's structure or iterating over the set each time to find the one I want?

UPDATE:
I accepted mVChr's answer because it worked and was the simplest solution even though it required a second map.

The solution we actually ended up going with was just using the country select box's index to index into the collection. This worked because our country dropdown was also being populated from our data structure. Here is how we indexed in...

```
countryStateMap[$('#country').attr("selectedIndex")]
```

If you need to do it any other way, use any of the below solutions.

Comment: For the most efficient solution you have to change your structure (from array to object).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you could do is cache a map so you only have to do the iteration once:

```
var csmMap = {};
for (var i = 0, cl = countryStateMap.length; i < cl; i++) {
  csmMap[countryStateMap[i].CountryCode] = i;
}
```

Then if `countryCode = 'CA'` you can find its states like:

```
countryStateMap[csmMap[countryCode]].States
```

Answer (score 2):

```
countryStateMap.get = function(cc) {
    if (countryStateMap.get._cache[cc] === void 0) {
        for (var i = 0, ii = countryStateMap.length; i < ii; i++) {
            if (countryStateMap[i].CountryCode === cc) {
                countryStateMap.get._cache[cc] = countryStateMap[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return countryStateMap.get._cache[cc];
}
countryStateMap.get._cache = {};
```

Now you can just call `.get("CA")` like so

`countryStateMap.get("CA").States`

If you prefer syntatic sugar you may be interested in [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) which has utility methods to make this kind of code easier to write

```
countryStateMap.get = _.memoize(function(cc) {
    return _.filter(countryStateMap, function(val) {
        val.CountryCode = cc;
    })[0];
});
```

[`_.memoize`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#memoize) , [`_.filter`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#select)

Answer (score 0):

love your local jQuery:

small little function for you:

> getByCountryCode = function(code){var res={};$.each(countryStateMap, function(i,o){if(o.CountryCode==code)res=o;return false;});return res}

so do this then:

> getByCountryCode("CA").States

and it returns:

> [Object, Object]